# Should an update statement query plan ever go parallel?

Tags: sql-server, update, parallelism

If an update statement's query plan does go parallel, does it guarantee a communication buffer resource deadlock, or is that determined by whether the parallel plan is using all cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#DOP):

> The update and delete operators in a parallel query execution plan are executed serially, but the WHERE clause of an UPDATE or a DELETE statement may be executed in parallel. The actual data changes are then serially applied to the database.

As to your second question,

> does it guarantee a communication buffer resource deadlock

Any deadlock is predicated on the query / queries being run and how they are structured and executed, SQL Server does not inherently guarantee any deadlocks on its own.

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for the link to the documentation, I was not able to find that earlier.  However, I wonder why this type of deadlock does not occur more frequently, particularly in Data Warehouses that process updates to dimension records?